# RoutingError with RSpec Controller test on Scoped Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rspec, scope, routes

So I have a route that looks like this:

```
scope "4" do
  scope "public" do
    scope ":apikey" do
      resources :shops
    end
  end
end
```

And a bunch of controller specs, an example of which looks like this:

```
describe ShopsController do

  describe "when responding to a GET" do

    context "#new" do
      it "should create a new instance of the shop class" do
        get :new
        @shop.should_not_be_nil
      end
    end

  end

end
```

In rake routes, as well as via a web browser, this controller/action works fine.  However, RSpec throws:

```
1) ShopsController when responding to a GET#new should create a new instance of the shop class
 Failure/Error: get :new
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"shops", :action=>"new"}
 # ./spec/controllers/shops_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I remove the `scope` statements from the route, the tests work fine.  Is there a way to "inform" RSpec of the route scopes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your routes, `:apikey` is a required parameter, so you need to add it to your get:

```
get :new, :apikey => "something"
```

Also you should change the expectation in your next line to this:

```
assigns[:shop].should_not be_nil
```

Use `assigns` to check the controller's instance variables, and separate `should_not` from the matcher with a space, not an underscore. That last bit takes some getting used to.